# How to attach copper wire (8 gauge) to wood (Eastern White Pine)?

Tags: adhesives, wood, metal

We are looking to add a bit of "bling" to a the bar in a nano-brewery tasting room. The front of the bar (where your legs go if you are sitting at the bar) is 8" tongue-and-groove with a V-groove at each joint. The material is Eastern White Pine (a softwood) and will be finished with a light stain.

The idea is to add visual interest by affixing a length of 8-gauge copper wire within each of the V-groves. The wire needs to be attached securely enough that it will not come free if someone's leg or foot hits the wall.

My question is what to use to attach the wire. My first thought is some sort of rounded copper staples. I actually have some staples that fit one of my staplers that would be perfect, but they are steel. I have not (yet) been able to find small copper staples, however.

Any other alternative suggestions for attaching the wire?

Comment: Hello Rob! Welcome to Arts and Crafts! For clarity, do you want to attach the wire so that it lays on top of the wood, above the joint, or will it be somewhat inlayed? If you are not receiving responses, your question may have better resuts if posted on the woodworking site: http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @EmRoBeau The intent is to inlay the wire in the center of the groove, so that it is partly recessed. Thanks for pointing out the woodworking site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copper grounding clamps have a nice industrial look to them and they come in all shapes and sizes, easily handle the 8awg requirement.

Though the copper staples would be a far more economical solution.

The Acme staples company carries copper staples. http://www.acmestaple.com/

Comment: [Acme, you say?](http://cdn2us.denofgeek.com/sites/denofgeekus/files/acme.jpg)